# How to hide statusbar without lifting icons up in Launcher?

Tags: android, statusbar, android-launcher

I want to hide statusbar in Launcher interface. I used code "window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);" to realize it. But the problem is while I long click on a desktop item, the statusbar is hidden, but the other Application icons will lift up. The season is the statusbar's place is gone, so the thing below it will go up. Does anyone know how to resolve the problem in an easy way? TKS in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer the question by myself.  Set the workspace margin dynamic.